# google.maps.Geocoder show null results

Tags: javascript, geolocation, geocoder

i am having multiple addresses names in an array and i am calculating their distance from my location. so i am using google.maps.geocoder() for this purpose. it is not calculating lat long of multiple address i have. and show error: `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT`
here is my code:

```
var myLocations = [];
function calculateDistance(){
//array of Addresses
var data = ["Shah Faisal Ave, E-8","G-6/4, Islamabad","AK Brohi Road, G-11/4","Jamia Muhammadia F6/4 Islamabad","Agha Nasir Road, F11/4","Plot 7, Street 9, Block C, Soan Gardens","Jamia Masjid Syedna Hussain, G-13/1, Islamabad","Andar Shehr Mohallah Baqir Shah, Peshawar Pakistan",
"Qissa Khwani Bazaar, Mohallah Baqir Shah","Gulshan-e-Iqbal, Karachi","Bahria Town, Karachi","DHA, Karachi","M.A Jinnah Road Karachi","Badshahi Mosque lahore","Bahria Town, Lahore, Pakistan",
"Naulakha Lahore Railway Station","Jamia masjid Road,Raja Bazar Rwp","New Shakrial' Zia Masjid Rawalpindi","Brockworth Crescent,BRISTOL CITY","islamabad","Sitara Market"];

var length = data.length;
for(i;i<length;i++){
              if(isNaN(data[i])){
                var address = data[i]['address'];
                getDistance(address,latlng);
              }
            }
}
  function getDistance(address,latlng){
  var distance;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                  {
                    var newdata = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                    distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(newdata, latlng)*0.000621371192;
                    var var1 = {distance: distance, address:address};
                    myLocations.push(var1);
                  }
                });
      geocoder = null;
}
```